# Linear Interpolation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work with crashes and mileage for the same year which is Year in table. Crashes are are there for every record, but annual mileage is not. NULLs for mileage could be at the beginning or at the end of the time period for certain customer. Also, couple of annual mileage records can be missing as well. I do not know how to overcome this. I try to do it in CASE statement but then I do not know how to code it properly. Issue needs to be resolved in SQL and use SQL Server.

This is how the output looks like and I need to have mileage for every single year for each customer.
The info I am pulling from is proprietary database and the records themselves should be untouched as is. I just need code in query which will modify my current output to output where I have mileage for every year. I appreciate any input!

| Year | Customer | Crashes | Annual_Mileage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | 123 | 5 | 3453453 |
| 2010 | 123 | 1 | NULL |
| 2011 | 123 | 0 | 54545 |
| 2012 | 123 | 14 | 376457435 |
| 2013 | 123 | 3 | 63453453 |
| 2014 | 123 | 4 | NULL |
| 2015 | 123 | 15 | 6346747 |
| 2016 | 123 | 0 | NULL |
| 2017 | 123 | 2 | 534534 |
| 2018 | 123 | 7 | NULL |
| 2019 | 123 | 11 | NULL |
| 2020 | 123 | 15 | 565435 |
| 2021 | 123 | 12 | 474567546 |
| 2022 | 123 | 7 | NULL |

Desired Results

| Year | Customer | Crashes | Annual_Mileage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009 | 123 | 5 | 3453453 |
| 2010 | 123 | 1 | 175399 (prior value is taken) |
| 2011 | 123 | 0 | 54545 |
| 2012 | 123 | 14 | 376457435 |
| 2013 | 123 | 3 | 63453453 |
| 2014 | 123 | 4 | 34900100 (avg of 2 adjacent values) |
| 2015 | 123 | 15 | 6346747 |
| 2016 | 123 | 0 | 3440641 (avg of 2 adjacent values) |
| 2017 | 123 | 2 | 534534 |
| 2018 | 123 | 7 | 534534 ( prior value is taken) |
| 2019 | 123 | 11 | 549985 (avg of 2 adjacent values) |
| 2020 | 123 | 15 | 565435 |
| 2021 | 123 | 12 | 474567546 |
| 2022 | 123 | 7 | 474567546 (prior value is taken) |

[image]

```
SELECT Year, 
       Customer,
       Crashes,
       CASE
         WHEN Annual_Mlg IS NOT NULL THEN Annual_Mlg
         WHEN Annual_Mlg IS NULL THEN
           CASE
             WHEN PREV.Annual_Mlg IS NOT NULL
              AND NEXT.Annual_Mlg IS NOT NULL
               THEN ( PREV.Annual_Mlg + NEXT.Annual_Mlg ) / 2
             ELSE 0
           END
       END AS Annual_Mlg 
FROM #table
```

The above code doesn't work, but I just need to start somehow and that what I have currently.
I understand what I need to do I just do not know how to code it in SQL.

After i applied row_number () function i got this output for first  2 clients and for the rest of the 4 clients row_number() function gave correct output. i have no idea why is that. I thought may be because i used "full join" before to combine mileage and crashes table?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9pgv.png)

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your table data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly that in your table you have say Year 2020 | Customer A and YEAR 2021 | Customer B only. But you want a result row for all years and customers, i.e. 2020|A, 2020|B, 2021|, 2021|B. And where you don't have a row in the table, you want to show the missing mileage as NULL. Yes?

Comment: Or are there no rows missing? Are the rows in the table, but the mileage is just null?

Comment: And instead of NULL you want to show the last mileage so far for the customer? So for customer 123 and 2020 you want to show the value of 2017, because 2018 and 2019 are missing?

Comment: Or don't you have one row per year and customer in the table at all? Do you have multiple rows per customer and year? Please edit your request and clarify all questions. Show simple sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: Instead of NULLs i need to have mileage. All NULLs should be gone. This snapshot in post was just example for one customer. I have unique id for each customer and years for each customer. When there is Annual mileage then value should be displayed in that filed untouched. IF there is NULL instead then there are multiple ways in which this can happen, some of them:

Comment: This is continuation of previous post.

Comment: This is continuation of previous post. I work in years range between 2009 - 2022. 1)If first record is NULL then code should pull mileage from next FIRST record where mileage is NOT null. Like if for example Year 2009 & 2010 had NULLs for mileage then it pulls number from year 2011 (assuming record is not null for 2011 mileage). 2) If LAST record (year 2022) has NULL for mileage then it pulls data from prior first record where mileage is not null.

Comment: This is continuation to my previous post. Case 3) If mileage value is NULL AND it is not first record (year 2009) or last record (year 2022) then average can be taken of 2 values (before and after NULL record). Average should be taken with mileage which are the most close to the year in which record is NULL. Example: Year 2011,2012,2013 have NULLs for mileage. Assuming we have mileage for year 2010 & 2014, then mileage for year 2011 will be average of years 2010 & 2014. Then, to find mileage for 2012, we use OBTAINED estimate from 2011 (from prior computation) and actual record 2014.

Comment: NOTE: roughly up to 50% is missing in table. There are NO instances where values for mileage are ALL NULLs for certain customer.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `#table` tells me that you're using MS SQL Server (a temporary table, probably in a stored procedure).

You want to:

- select all the rows in `#table`
- joined with the matching row (if any) for the previous year, and
- joined with the matching row (if any) for the next year

Then it's easy. Assuming the primary key on your `#table` is composed of the `year` and `customer` columns, something like this ought to do you:

```
select t.year     ,
       t.customer ,
       t.crashes  ,
       annual_milage = coalesce(
         t.annual_milage ,
         ( coalesce( p.annual_mileage, 0 ) +
           coalesce( n.annual_mileage, 0 )
         ) / 2
       )
from      #table t                            -- take all the rows
left join #table p on p.year     = t.year - 1 -- with the matching row for
                  and p.customer = t.customer --   the previous year (if any)
left join #table n on n.year     = t.year + 1 -- and the matching row for
                  and n.customer = t.customer --   the next year (if any)
```

**Notes:**

- What value you default to if the previous or next year doesn't exist is up to you (zero? some arbitrary value?)
- Is the previous/next year guaranteed to be the current year +/- 1?

  If not, you may have to use *derived tables* as the source for the
  prev/next data, selecting the closest previous/next year (that sort
  of thing rather complicates the query significantly).

**Edited To Note:**

If you have discontiguous years for each customer such that the "previous" and "next" years for a given customer are not necessarily the current year +/- 1, then something like this is probably the most straightforward way to find the previous/next year.

We use a *derived table* in our from clause, and assign a sequential number in lieu of year for each customer, using the *ranking function* [`row_number()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function. This query, then

```
select row_nbr = row_number() over (
                   partition by x.customer
                   order by     x.year
                 ) ,
       x.*
from #table x
```

would produce results along these lines:

| row_nbr | customer | year | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1992 | ... |
| 2 | 123 | 1993 | ... |
| 3 | 123 | 1995 | ... |
| 4 | 123 | 2020 | ... |
| 1 | 456 | 2001 | ... |
| 2 | 456 | 2005 | ... |
| 3 | 456 | 2020 | ... |

And that leads us to this:

```
select year           = t.year     ,
       customer       = t.customer ,
       crashes        = t.crashes  ,
       annual_mileage = coalesce(
                          t.mileage,
                          coalesce(
                            t.annual_mileage,
                            (
                              coalesce(p.annual_mileage,0) +
                              coalesce(n.annual_mileage,0)
                            ) / 2
                          ),
                        )
from (
       select row_nbr = row_number() over (
                          partition by x.customer
                          order by     x.year
                        ) ,
              x.*
       from #table x
     ) t
left join #table p on p.customer = t.customer and p.row_nbr = t.row_nbr-1
left join #table n on n.customer = t.customer and n.row_nbr = t.row_nbr+1
```

Comment: Thank you, Nicholas! Regarding 3rd point in notes. That actually is the case. I will test the code you provided. Much appreciated! Also, if i do not have first value i use first next available value; if i do not have last value i use first prior available value; if null is between 2 non-NULL values for mileage then i use average instead.

Comment: Hello, Nicholas! Regarding point 2 in your notes above. No, it is NOT the case that prev/next year to be current year +/- 1. I found instance where let's say record is there for 2012, then record is missing for 2013 but then there is record for 2015. I am OK with that as long as mileage field is completely filled. However, there is an issue when NULL value is sandwiched between 2 non-NULLs. Code should take avg of those 2 non-NULLs. Instead, currently code copies previous mileage.

Comment: Hello, Nicholas! I would appreciate if you can elaborate on point 3 in your notes. Thank you!

Comment: Good day, Nicholas! Thank you for help. i am getting closer to completely working code for me and i am doing best to understand what i am doing wrong somewhere. I used your row number() function to partition by customer and strangely for 2 customer numbers i am getting strange results. Please see the snapshot of what i got. However, then code started to work properly. I used before full join to get year field to be completed as much as possible. This is because crashes do not happen every year and mileage is not recorded every year for customer. So, i used 'full join' to combine those 2 tables

Comment: This is continuation to prior comment. So, i used 'full join' to combine crashes and mileage tables. This way i have nearly all years in my combined  table which i initially just called '#table' in my post. I just try to figure out why code behaves this way. Any help is appreciated.  For first 2 customers output is weird (rows are not enumerated the way they should be) but then output is correct. I try to figure out how to fix that error. I attached screenshot above. Thank you!

Comment: Issue is basically in the following. Enumeration happens for 2 different clients at the same time. Like there are 2 rows which are #1 for Year 2009 and clients id are different. This oscillation happens until i get to Year 2022. After that for other clients output is correct and enumeration is correct as well. How to find out what is wrong?

Comment: Good day, Nicholas! I appreciate ALL your answers! God Bless you! What if I do not want to replace with default NULLs. What i need is that NULLs either should be replaced by previous non-NULL value, next non-NULL value or interpolation between 2 non-NULLs should get rid of NULLs completely. Is this possible to do in MS SQL Server? Thank you! Your code defaults to 0 if NULL cannot be replaced, but i do NOT need to have default value at all. Thank you!